# how to send php command from javascript to php file

Tags: javascript, php

i am trying to send php command from javascript using innerhtml but it send the command commented how can i fix that

```
document.getElementById('ThirdOption').innerHTML = "<?php DisplayLocation() ?>";
```

The result i got on html div is as following

```
<!--?php DisplayLocation() ?-->
```

Comment: run it off a webserver with the right protocol

Comment: PHP run at the server, not in the client, so to access something server side, use AJAX

Comment: Clear example of someone not doing their research before posting